# Getting items from JsonArray dynamically no matter what is the type using GSON

Tags: java, arrays, gson

I got this JsonArray:

```
   "jokes": [
      {
        "description": "Knock Knock joke of the day!",
        "language": "en",
        "background": "",
        "category": "knock-knock",
        "date": "2019-12-02",
        "joke": {
          "title": "Knock Knock - Raoul who?",
          "lang": "en",
          "length": "64",
          "clean": "1",
          "racial": "0",
          "id": "GcLEyRMil3Od8VaaNtGo5QeF",
          "text": "Knock Knock\r\nWho's there?\r\nRaoul!\r\nRaoul who?\r\nRaoul of law!\r\n\r\n"
        }
      }
    ],
    "copyright": "2019-20 https://jokes.one"
  }
}
```

I want to be able to retrieve any item from the json array with no importance for the data type ,
for example if I want to get JsonObject `joke` I implemented this function:

```
public static JsonObject getJsonObjectFromJsonArray(int index, String fieldName, JsonArray jsonArray) {
        return jsonArray.get(index).getAsJsonObject().get(fieldName).getAsJsonObject();
    }
```

and if I want to retrieve json element which is string I implmeneted this function:

```
   public static String getItemStringFromJsonArray(int index, String fieldName, JsonArray jsonArray){
        return jsonArray.get(index).getAsJsonObject().get(fieldName).getAsString();
    }
```

those two last methods looks the same but return different data types , how can I make it generic?

Answer (score 0):

No pro solution could be set the variable type as object. Other solution it is if the value has some common found, you can set a parent class and use it as mayor class when defining. Or (pro solution for me) use Java 11 and define them as var.